# What communication protocols are used with mobile displays?

Tags: embedded, serial, protocol, serial-bus

I have been researching the communication protocols used between the motherboard/processor of touch screens used in phones and smart watches for a while, but I couldn't find much.

Generally, communication between them is established with FPC cable, but what is the communication protocol used between them?

Comment: I would be surprised if manufacturers make this public

Comment: MIPI? Not nearly enough info to tell. FPC is a construction method, not a communication standard.  Check datasheets of nearby parts?

Comment: If it helps to know: I once tore the lcd cable in a phone partway and it stopped the display of 50% of the columns of the screen, suggesting that each portion of the screen was driven by a different differential pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the smart phones and embedded electronics are now using the MIPI standard for communication. MIPI stands for "Mobile Industry Processor Interface". There are diversity of protocol that are there in MIPI like MIPI-DSI, MIPI-CSI, MIPI-serial and so on. In general the display streaming is done via such protocol and other interfaces like touch, LED brightness can all be communicated I2C protocol.

Comment: Is there any resources that I can read? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The display connection for my iPhone SE (2016) is MIPI according to the schematics:

[image: iPhone SE schematic portion]

Comment: Can you share with me all schematics and sheets about it?

Comment: @omerkarslioglu I am unaware of the legalities of that, however a quick google search for "iphone se 2016 schematics" yields "About 1,050,000 results" which include the popular and reasonably safe gsmforums. Have a look around and I bet you'll find this material easily.